# Bootstrap 3 Modal with texarea inside. When tap/focus on textarea, the background scrolls to top. Only in iOS 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, ios8

I'm using Bootstrap 3.2.0.

I can show the modal just fine and the background stays in place. The modal contains a `textarea`. When I tap or focus on that textarea and the virtual keyboard comes up, the background scrolls to the top.

This only happens with iOS 8 and not iOS 7.

It's like iOS 8 wants to put whatever is focused on in the middle of the screen and it scrolls until that element is in the middle. It scrolls up and up and up until it hits the top THEN pulls the modal down a little.

Very frustrating. Has anyone experienced this yet? Any solutions?

Update: I'm thinking it has to do with the fact that the modal is `fixed` position and not `absolute`. iOS wants to put the focused element in the middle of the screen so it scrolls the viewport or document up until the element is in center but scrolling does nothing because the element is position fixed.

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support-fixed-position-keyboards Virtual keyboards

Also, note that if you're using inputs in your modal or navbar, iOS has a rendering bug that doesn't update the position of fixed elements when the virtual keyboard is triggered. A few workarounds for this include transforming your elements to position: absolute or invoking a timer on focus to try to correct the positioning manually. This is not handled by Bootstrap, so it is up to you to decide which solution is best for your application.

Comment: On those modals only, make it position absolute.

Comment: Thanks @Christina, I'm working on setting those elements to `position: absolute;` and determining what the new top value will be.

Comment: Just make the background top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0; position:absolute.

Comment: onscreen keyboard == dom-gremlin. beware of being too fancy with positioning anywhere an onscreen keyboard is involved. you never know what they are going to do or how they are going to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me was to set the modal involved to `position:absolute;` (by default it is `position: fixed;`) and instead of placing the modal at the bottom of my HTML by appending it to the body, I appended it to the parent element of the button that I clicked to show the modal. I also needed to ensure that the element that I was appending the modal into had a position of relative.

**CSS**

```
.modal.fade.my-special-modal {
    position: absolute;
    /* 'top' is not required but I did it for my taste */
    top: 15px;
}

.my-special-modal-container {
    position: relative;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="my-special-modal-container">
    <button>Show the modal</button>
    <!-- js will inject the modal here -->
</div>
```

Thanks to @Christina for helping me discover this solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can add this property globally:

```
if( navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i) ) {
    var styleEl = document.createElement('style'), styleSheet;
    document.head.appendChild(styleEl);
    styleSheet = styleEl.sheet;
    styleSheet.insertRule(".modal { position:absolute; bottom:auto; }", 0);
 }
```